trix autofocus issue on expreessJS/ejs
I'm building a blog, with NodeJS/Express, and use Trix editor to handle writing and editing the blog posts. while attempting to edit a post trix rich text area automatically fouces; not allowing any edits to other text areas on the page.
The following is the EJS code for the edit post pages with Trix editor tag added

  <form action="/edit-post/<%= data._id %>?_method=PUT" method="POST" autofocus ='false'>
      <label for="title"><b>Title</b></label>
      <input autofocus="true" type="text" placeholder="Post Title" name="title" value="<%= data.title %>">


     
      <label for="body"><b>Content</b></label>
      
       <input id="x" type="hidden" name="body"" autofocus="false"> // here is where the issue happening 
      <trix-editor input="x" autofocus="false"> <%= data.body %> </trix-editor>
      <input type="submit" value="Update" class="btn">
  </form>


how to fix this issue?

The autofocus attribute isn't meant to be specified on several elements next to each other. Furthermore the attribute, like all the other boolean attributes, does not accept true or false as value.
As the HTML5 spec describes on their page about boolean attributes:

The presence of a boolean attribute on an element represents the true value, and the absence of the attribute represents the false value. If the attribute is present, its value must either be the empty string or a value that is an ASCII case-insensitive match for the attribute's canonical name, with no leading or trailing whitespace.

Meaning that boolean attributes can only be set in three ways
<textarea autofocus></textarea>
<textarea autofocus=""></textarea>
<textarea autofocus="autofocus"></textarea> <!--could also write `autofocus="aUtOfOcUs"`-->

And the only way to set the attribute to false for an element, is the absence of the attribute.
It could be that some browser still accept any value, as MDN docs mentiones on their page about boolean attributes:

Though modern browsers treat any string value as true, you should not rely on that behavior.

Additionally something concerning the autofocus attribute, is that you should not have more than 1 element having the autofocus attribute in the same document or dialog:

No more than one element in the document or dialog may have the autofocus attribute. If applied to multiple elements the first one will receive focus.

So you should only put the attribute on that element you want to be focused on page load.
Links to read more about boolean attributes and autofocus:

Stackoverflow question

is it autofocus="autofocus" or autofocus?
What values can appear in the "selected" attribute of the "option" tag?


MDN docs

autofocus: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/autofocus
boolean attributes: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Boolean/HTML


HTML5 spec (W3)

autofocus: https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/interaction.html#the-autofocus-attribute
boolean attributes: https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/common-microsyntaxes.html#boolean-attribute



